# using .getScript() in combination with a conditional function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

my if statement doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts? Essentially with my website I'm using the fullpage.js plugin. If you go to the website, http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/ and inspect element (in chrome) and go right to the next page (Our ethos), it will gain the class active on the end of its HTML identifier. percentagecircles.js is a js file I use for animation. I'm trying to make the percentagecircles.js only run when that page is essentially 'active'...

```
if ($('#fullpage > div > div.fp-slides > div > div.slide.fp-slide.fp-table').hasClass('active'))
{
  $.getScript("http://carrotcrunchpvp.comule.com/percentagecircles.js");
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have the following error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - intialisation.js:2`

Comment: It's not coming up on my console... either way, it isn't effecting my problem here

Answer (score 0):

You need to make make use of the callbacks provided by fullPage.js such as `afterSlideLoad` or `afterLoad`.

You will find them explained [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

This way you can get the active slide and work with it.
In any case, you don't want to use `getScript`. You probably want to include it since the start and only initialise it when needed.